# Can I use drivers from an older ubuntu on a newer release?

Tags: graphics, intel

I dug an older (circa 2000) PC out of the garage to teach my kids linux and text mode programming. The motherboard has an intel chipset and the graphics chip is the Intel 82810E. When I install the latest Ubuntu my attached display shows a garbage character set, making the console unreadable. I found out, however, that the 6.10 Ubuntu release supported this chipset; in fact, I installed 6.10 and it worked like a charm. My question now is "How can I get the graphics driver from 6.10 and install it on my 14.04 release?

Comment: I really don't remember if Ubuntu reads from `/etc/vconsole.conf`, but if that's the case you should try setting `FONT` in `/etc/vconsole.conf`.

Comment: You are better off picking something else than Ubuntu.  Ubuntu before and after Unity is a completely different system.  Plus the hardware stacks   we have drop support for older hardware and add new hardware. I doubt 2006 hardware is still in the HWE stacks. Or toss the system and get a new one ;-)

Comment: I have thought about getting a completely different system but I like this one. It is a fanless Compaq iPaq. It is a 1Ghz PIII with 512MB of RAM. It uses very little power and sits under my desk making zero noise. I realize it can't do anything substantial but I don't need that right now. It is free and does what I need when I connect via ssh. It would just be nice if the console worked.

Comment: Ok. My ubuntu install is psychic. I downloaded the Fedora install DVD thinking that maybe another distro would have the correct driver. I burnt the image to a disc and booted but the drive door wasn't quite closed and it booted into Ubuntu off the hard drive. I left the room and when I came back the console was suddenly readable in plain text. I had restarted several times prior to that and each time the display was wrong. I don't know what fixed it but whatever it was, I now have a working ubuntu server installation for my network. Thanks to all that contributed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why it should be a problem. As long the current kernel is backward-compatible with the kernel used in 6.10, you should be fine.

[Here's](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu:Edgy/Repositories/) a guide on how to add repos from an older Ubuntu release onto the current version

Answer (score 0):

I would rather download the [source](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/1645/Linux-Graphics-Driver-TAR-XFCOM-I810-1-2-PATCH-TAR-GZ-?product=81533) of the 82810 Intel driver, compile and install on UBUNTU 14.04. The old driver from 6.1 must not be forward compatible. The newer kernel versions have often renamed the names of the functions. I would even wonder when the 6.1 driver would work on 14.04.